# Can we assign private IP address on serial port of a router

Tags: router, ip-address, serial-port

I know that serial port is used for communication with wan so it must have a public ip address. But is this possible to assign a private ip address to a serial port if so then what can be the reason ?

Comment: Serial ports do not use Internet Protocol (except for SLIP).  Routers typically do not have a serial port (especially the cheap consumer-grade unmanaged ones).

Comment: @sawdust: nowadays IP is definitely used on serial lines, over SLIP, PPP or (most commonly, I think) HDLC.

Comment: @kaleem, look up 'leased line'.

Answer (score 0):

WAN does not equal Internet.

A serial line can be used to e.g. connect two office buildings to each other, or to connect a site to an MPLS cloud.

And even if the line would be used to connect to an ISP for Internet access, then it's still not strictly necessary to use public ip addresses on that link, although it is best practice.